# Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.Char"

Tags: powershell

I am just getting started with powershell and I'm making a very simple encryption function. I want to take each char in a string, convert it to a int and add a chosen number then convert it back to a char.

This works fine:

```
function encrypt($a){
  $letter=[int][char]$a
  $letter=$letter+1;
  return [char]$letter
}
encrypt("test)
```

But this does not:

```
function encrypt($a, $key){
  $letter=[int][char]$a
  $letter=$letter+$key;
  return [char]$letter
}
encrypt("test", 1)
```

It gives me the error in the title.. what am I missing?

Comment: the function is supposed to take a single char as parameter so its encrypt("t") instead of encrypt("test")

Answer (score 4):

You are merley passing your parameters in the wrong way:

```
encrypt "t" 1
```

works.

Powershell will treat `("t", 1)` as a single parameter.

Since you haven't specified any parameter as mandatory, powershell will just use the order in which you give parameters. So the first parameter give is used to fill the variable `$a`. You can also call parameters with name in any order:

```
encrypt -key 5 -a a
f
```

Also powershell can't parse a whole string (e.g. "test") as a char, it always needs to be a single character. If you want your function to able to take entire string, you could do something like this:

```
function encrypt($word,$offset){
    foreach ($letter in $word.toCharArray()) {
        $letter=[int]$letter+$offset;
        $return = $return + [char]$letter
    }
    return $return
}
```

This should provide what you are looking for:

```
encrypt "test" 2
vguv
```